# Vaadin Grid row height

Tags: css, vaadin7

I want to reduce cell size so to fit more rows in screen.
[screen][1]
 so far i have used

```
.v-grid-cell {
    font-size: 13px;
    height: 18px;
    vertical-align: middle; 
}
.v-grid-row{
    height: 18px;

}
.v-grid-row-odd {
    height: 18px;
    background-color: #EFF0F1;
}
```

and the [result][2]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting a `line-height` on `.v-grid-cell`:

```
.v-grid-cell {  
    line-height: 18px;
}
```

This isn't really a Sass question though, it's just general plain 'ol CSS.

Comment: thanks for the answer, i sort of figure out my self :)

Answer (score 0):

try to reduce the font size of the grid. Try like below.

```
.v-grid-cell {
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

Comment: does this help you @Nabeel Khan ?