# Applying user defined CSS to Grid in Vaadin 7

Tags: css, grid, vaadin

In my application I have two Vaadin Grids. I want to apply default CSS to one grid and user defined CSS to the other. When I apply the user defined CSS to the other grid, the default CSS is dominating over the user defined CSS. Here are my code. 
In `styles.scss`,

```
.my-grid-style{
    line-height: 64px !important;
   font-size: 12px !important;
   text-align: center !important;
}
```

In my application .java file I am using `setStyleName` as follows

```
grid.setStyleName("my-grid-style");
```

but this CSS is dominated by the default `.v-grid-cell` style. Can anyone suggest how to achieve the same?

Comment: Does setting this style to .v-grid-cell helps? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34438195/vaadin-grid-row-height

Comment: Setting the style to `.v-grid-cell` applies style on both all grids. I want to apply style to a specific grid only.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
.my-grid-style {
  .v-grid-cell {
    //your styles
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your style is not adding to styles.Because of the default CSS can't dominate to "!important"
Try to add with programmatically:

```
UI.getCurrent().getPage().getStyles().add(".my-grid-style{\n" +
                                          "    line-height: 64px !important;\n" +
                                          "   font-size: 12px !important;\n" +
                                          "   text-align: center !important;\n" +
                                          "}");
```

then

```
grid.setStyleName("my-grid-style");
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me (not sure if you need .v-grid-body [ollitietavainen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3608089/ollitietavainen) didn't use it, but it may be important for other functions like editors )

```
UI.getCurrent().getPage().getStyles().add(
    ".my-grid-style .v-grid-body .v-grid-cell {\n" +"" +
    "     line-height: 18px;\n" + 
    "     font-size: 12px;\n" + 
    "}");
```

then use the style as discussed by [utrucceh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3095500/utrucceh)

```
grid.setStyleName("my-grid-style");
```

It sure would be nice if one of the following 'built-ins' worked like they did for the Table component:

```
grid.addStyleName(ValoTheme.TABLE_COMPACT); // "compact"
grid.addStyleName(ValoTheme.TABLE_SMALL); // "small"
```